# Is it possible to copy and paste features in an online Edit function?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, editing, copy

Using the ESRI JS API, is it possible to select a feature and then create buttons to copy and paste that feature?  This would be done using the Editor Widget.  If its possible to do this, but only retain the shape (loosing the attributes) I could live with that.  If its not possible using the ESRI JS API, can it be done simply with Dojo?

Comment: By copy and paste, do you mean to the same location, or to a location of your choice?

Comment: Same location - just like it would in an ArcMAP session.  User can then use the move tool to shift the location.

Answer (score 3):

the editor widget doesn't include any convenient tools to copy/paste existing geometries.  this means you would have to make your own call to featureLayer.applyEdits(), passing in the geometry of an existing graphic as a newly added feature

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/featurelayer-amd.html#applyedits