# Copy and paste feature using ArcGIS Online editing?

Tags: editing, arcgis-online, copy

Wondering if there is a way to copy and paste a feature (geometry and attributes) using ArcGIS online editing.  I have searched the internet a bit and have been unable to find any way to do it.

Comment: You can right click and copy layers within map viewer.

Comment: Not a duplicate, but a related Q&A 
http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/90515/is-it-possible-to-copy-and-paste-features-in-an-online-edit-function